# java - path to trustStore - why it's not working?

Tags: java, ssl, truststore

I have used this in the vm arguments:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/certs/trust.p12 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=WebAS
```

also tried to setup by code:

```
System.setProperty("com.ibm.ssl.trustStore", "/opt/certs/trust.p12");
System.setProperty("com.ibm.ssl.trustStorePassword", "WebAS");
```

In both ways, I am getting the below exception:

```
Message Key:CWPKI0029E: SSL context provider "IBMJSSE2" is not valid.  This provider is specified in the SSL configuration alias "DefaultSystemProperties" loaded from SSL configuration file "null".
```

The extended error message is: `"no such provider: IBMJSSE2". not found in resource bundle:com.ibm.ws.ssl.resources.ssl`

Any clue please.

Comment: Try to add -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=PKCS12

Answer (score 0):

are you using a standalone separate client ?

If you are, its possible, but you need to re-create the entire WSAdmin environment around your code and make sure you are using the IBM JDK at the same version as the WebSphere you are targetting.

I've just managed to create a pure Jython standalone client that securely connects to WebSphere, but all variables across wsadmin.bat and setupcmdline???.bat had to be catered for.